# make duplicate levels unique in r

Tags: r, unique, r-factor

I have to extract data for each individual from one large file based on a date/time window from another file.  I have ID, Start, End date as my window file and a huge file (FULLDATA) with all sorts of other data in it, but we shall just simplify it and say it has only ID, Date, X, Y, Z.

Eg., Dates window Data file

```
ID   Start              End Date         
c1    03/03/03  01:02    03/15/03 12:00
a2    03/03/03  04:35    03/10/03 13:00   
f3    02/03/03  11:02    05/15/03 15:00
c1    01/03/04  13:02    02/15/05 17:00
a2    04/23/04  04:02    05/14/05 10:00
```

There are duplicate ID's but unique windows of time I need to get data from.

In my code I need to set the levels

```
IDNames = levels(dates$ID)
```

but in doing this it will make the ID levels unique and only use the window from the 1st time that level showed.  So, in my example c1 and a2 will only be used 1 time and extract the information from their first appearance.

I have tried

```
levels(make.unique(IDNames))
```

But this then will turn the ID "c1" into "c1.1" which will not match up with the FULLDATA file in the rest of my commands.

```
for (n in 1:(length(IDNames))) {
  IndivData = FULLDATA[FULLDATA$ID==IDNames[n],]
  Dateswindow = dates[dates$ID==IDNames[n],]
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, wouldn't the row number do what you want? Since no two rows apparently should have the same id?!

Comment: No, row number wouldn't work...I don't think.  Because there are multiple duplicates of Start and End dates, they are only unique by ID.  So, I have to have it specifically say please pull out the data between these dates for individual 1.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like you want to produce a single column that identifies a unique combination of `ID`, `Start` and `End Date`, that in some sense preserves each piece so that you can refer to them using another data frame.

Why not simply coerce everything to characters and paste them together with a useful separating character? So something like:

```
IDNames <- paste(as.character(dates$ID),as.character(...),as.character(...),sep = "-")
```

Then you'll have a unique value for each ID-Start-End combination, and you can easily pull each piece out again to use to merge back with your other data.

Comment: So I would have to make this type of column in both files?  Basically creating a unique value to be able to sort and reference by?

Comment: @Kerry Sure, I guess. But to be honest, your description of what you're doing is really confusing.

Comment: I have a data set that just has a window of dates for 1 animal. These dates correspond to a behavior. EG. a bear between Sept 15-Nov 15 is hibernating & between May 12-June 15 it is fishing on a river. I have 30 bears, all having multiple behaviors & a window of time corresponding to those behaviors.  Another file is the complete data set of tracking the bear locations 5 times a day for 3 years. I want to extract the data from the FULL DATA that correspond to the to the WINDOW DATA. There is more than one behavior/individual it will show up more than once with different windows of time.

Comment: so the question is, how to use one file to sort through another file and give me all the data between each set of designated window dates?